# How to find results that do NOT match a keyword?

Tags: solr, solrnet

Is there any way I can user a NOT or other negation operator before a text search keyword for example,

```
NOT program
```

When I do such a search there are 0 records returned.
Please let me know some way to achieve this option.

Answer (score 1):

In Solr you can use the '-' minus sign as a NOT operator, so you would change your query to be

```
*:* - program
```

If you are using SolrNet, since that is how your question is tagged, you can do the following

```
solr.Query(new SolrQuery("*:*") && !new SolrQuery("program"));
```

Please see [Querying in SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Querying) for more details.

**Updated:** Per comment from Mauricio Scheffer

Comment: just a nitpick: purely negative queries don't work very well, you have to do `*:* -program` instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Mauricio. I have not done any purely negative queries. I was just going off the Solr documentation.

Answer (score -2):

There aren't any search operators that perform the search parameters you are describing. My advice is to use the Google advanced search features. You can make your search much more specific in a number of ways, its really advanced.

Comment: This is about Solr, not Google.